# Merge all possible combinations of multiple data frames

Tags: r, loops, merge

I would like to merge by columns all the possible pair combinations of these three data frames (i.e. nine combinations)

```
frame1 = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,2,3), c=c(1,2,3))
frame2 = data.frame(a=c(2,1,3), b=c(2,1,3), c=c(2,1,3))
frame3 = data.frame(a=c(3,2,1), b=c(3,2,1), c=c(3,2,1))
```

which contain the same 3 rows each but not in the same order, so I would also like that the merging be by coincidence of the pair of values of the columns a and b in the two files merged. Example:

```
a b c
1 1 1 
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

+

```
a b c
2 2 2
1 1 1   
3 3 3
```

=

```
a.x b.x c.x a.y b.y c.y
1 1 1 1 1 1  
2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3
```

I wanted then to obtain the difference between each pair of values of the columns c.x and c.y present in each merged file, in absolute values, and sum all these differences thus obtaining a "score" (of course this would be zero in this example), which I would like to add to an empty matrix 3x3 in the correspondant cell (i.e., the score of frame1 vs. frame 2 should be located in cell [2,1], etc.):

```
nframes = 3
frames = c(frame1,frame2,frame3)

matrix = matrix(, nrow = nframes, ncol = nframes)
matrix_scores = data.frame(matrix)

for (i in frames){
  for (j in frames)
   {
    x = merge(i, j, by=c("a","b"))
    score = sum(abs(x$c.x - x$c.y))
    matrix_scores[j,i] <- score
  }
}
```

However, when I run the loop I obtain the following message:

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns
```

Also, I understand that the line

```
matrix_scores[j,i] <- score
```

will give an error, too, but I do not know how to express that I want the score to be stored in cell [1,1], for the first iteration of the loop (frame1 vs. frame1).

The resulting matrix should be a 3x3 matrix containing all zeros:

```
       f1 f2 f3
frame1 0 0 0
frame2 0 0 0
frame3 0 0 0
```

Comment: Your code is problematic in a few places. You haven't stored your data frames in lists, instead you used `frames = c(frame1, frame2,..)`. The concatenate function is not correct here `list(frame1, frame2,...)` might be better. In the loops, The same data frame will merge with itself sometimes.

Comment: After changing that, the error became `Error in seq_len(nrows)[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Comment: I did not say that that is your final solution. I'm showing you the first error of many in your approach. If you would like to use `c()` then go ahead and have a good time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
# Put all frames in a list
d <- list(frame1, frame2, frame3)
# get all merge-combinations
gr <- expand.grid(1:length(d), 1:length(d))

# function to merge and get the sum diff:
foo <- function(i, x, gr){
  tmp <- merge(x[[gr[i, 1]]], x[[gr[i, 2]]], by=c("a", "b"))
  sum(abs(tmp$c.x - tmp$c.y))
}

# result matrix
matrix(sapply(1:nrow(gr), foo, d, gr), length(d), length(d),  byrow = T)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0

# The scores are set as followed:
matrix(apply(gr, 1, paste, collapse="_"), 3, 3,  byrow = T)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "1_1" "2_1" "3_1"
[2,] "1_2" "2_2" "3_2"
[3,] "1_3" "2_3" "3_3"


# alternative using apply:

# function to merge and get the sum diff:
foo <- function(y, x){
  tmp <- merge(x[[ y[1] ]], x[[ y[2] ]], by=c("a", "b"))
  sum(abs(tmp$c.x - tmp$c.y))
}
# result matrix
matrix(apply(gr, 1, foo, d), length(d), length(d),  byrow = T)
```

Comment: Thank you Jimbou, it looks like what I wanted, but it gives me an error after `gr <- expand.grid(1:length(x), 1:3)` : `Error in expand.grid(1:length(x), 1:3) : object 'x' not found`

Comment: @Michael I fixed that. You have to change the `x` to a `d`. See also that I included the `byrow` argument to build the matrix rowwise. Please consider to accept it as useful answer.

Comment: Yes now it works, I accept it but please just add this to the function: `sum(abs(tmp$r.2.x - tmp$r.2.y))`, since I want the absolute values. Otherwise it works perfect, thank you very much!